# Updating NSMutableArray of dictionary objects

Tags: iphone, dictionary, sdk, nsmutablearray

I have a NSMutableArray (i.e. "stories") of dictionary items.

I can read the dictionary items in the array just fine, e.g.

```
[[[stories objectAtIndex: b] objectForKey: @"title"]
```

But, now I am trying to update (i.e. replace) a couple of objects e.g. "title" & "matchingword", but I cannot find the right code.  Any suggestions are much appreciated.

I tried this, but it seems to be adding entirely new objects to the array

```
NSMutableDictionary *itemAtIndex = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[itemAtIndex setObject:[[placesArray objectAtIndex:a]objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"reference"];
[stories replaceObjectAtIndex:x withObject:itemAtIndex];  // replace "reference" with user's unique key
[itemAtIndex release];
```

I also tried this (but didn't work either):

```
//NSMutableDictionary *itemAtIndex2 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
//[itemAtIndex2 setObject:[separatePlaces objectAtIndex:x] forKey:@"matchingword"];
//[stories insertObject:itemAtIndex2 atIndex:x];  // add the unique matching word to story
//[itemAtIndex2 release];
```

Help appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grab the dictionary you want to mod.

```
NSMutableDictionary *temp = [stories objectAtIndex: b];
```

The change the value:

```
[temp setObject:@"new Info" forKey:@"title"];
```

Comment: Thanks.  It proved to be a bit more complicated.  For reasons that I don't understand, the above created a error at runtime saying I was trying to change an immutable object.  I checked and everything in the array was mutable.  So I added:  tempDict = [[stories objectAtIndex: b] mutableCopy]; I updated the objects but they would not save into the first dictionary, so copied the results into a new dictionary.  This works great.  Thanks.